Artificial Satellites Orbit Around a Cube with Uniform Surface Gravity
A cube-world with uniform surface gravity has been made using extremely strong materials of varying densities, and is orbiting a star, rotating on a axis between two corners (like spinning a d6). Due to the odd density distribution of the planet (which is required for the uniform surface gravity), the gravitational field is cube-like near the surface of the planet.
In relatively distant orbits, such as a lunar orbit, these anomalies can mostly be ignored. At lower orbits, they cannot. Is there any way artificial satellites can be put into a stable orbit around such a planet? If so, what would such an orbit look like?
In addition to the more general question, there's a couple more specific questions I have about certain interactions:

How low an orbit would a "low cube-world orbit" be compared to earth, if it was possible at all?
Would 4-face parallel orbits be possible (around the side of a d6 resting on a face)?


What do you mean by stable?  I ask because we do all sorts of clever things to deal with perturbations.  Which stable traits matter to you will help define the orbits.  An example is sun synch, which precesses, but we chose that precession carefully to keep satellites in the sun.

By "Stable" I mean able to stay in orbit mostly indefinitely with minimal fuel.

Although this answer may be incomplete, I considered a square star on a X-Y plane (not a cube) and ignore rotation. To create a gravitational potential that is as square as possible, I arranged a large number of mass points using DE algorithm. If you fill the gaps between the points with a sponge, we will have a square star where gravity spreads vertically downward.

The blue dots in the diagram are mass points of the same weight, and the circles are contours of gravitational potential (vectors perpendicular to the contour represent gravity force).

For the orbit that starts at the initial position (0, h) and closes in one loop, the minimum h was approximately 1.35~1.40 (ex. black curve in the diagram). Contrary to my expectations, no more "square" orbits were found. If the initial position is any lower, a satellite either collides with a corner or flies off into the depths of space. (orange). Furthermore, even a slight change in speed from the black line orbit results in complex paths (green). This is in contrast to the case with a single mass point, which results in an elliptical orbit.
I am rank amateur on orbital mechanics, so I am not sure if such an orbit is called "stable," but it seems dangerous to take a low orbit around this star.

What software did you use to produce your plots?
